# PHP Object Oriented - Whats the right way?

Tags: php, oop, object, mysqli

I started learning Object Oriented in PHP recently, and I have this small code. 
I have this code in class.php:

```
## Teacher
class Teacher
{
    public $_id;
    public $_name;
    public $_phone;

    public function create($id, $name, $phone) {
        $this->_id = $id;
        $this->_name = $name;
        $this->_phone = $phone;
    }
}

## Lesson
class Lesson
{
    public $_teacher;
    public $_student;
    public $_price;
    public $_date;

    public function create($teacher,$student,$price,$date)
    {
        $this->_teacher = $teacher;
        $this->_student = $student;
        $this->_price = $price;
        $this->_date = $date;
    }
}
```

**mysql.php:**

```
## MySQL Database Connection

$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "foo";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    echo "Connected successfully";
}

// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE $dbname";

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE teachers (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
phone VARCHAR(50)
)";

$conn->query($sql);
```

and I have this in index.php:

```
include_once('mysql.php');
include_once('class.php');

## PHP Code
$teacher1 = new Teacher();
$teacher1->create(324,"Ben","054","Audi TT");
var_dump($teacher1);

## PHP Code
$lesson1 = new Lesson();
$lesson1->create($teacher1->_id,date("D d/m/Y H:i"),240,2);
var_dump($lesson1);
```

I want to do something with the database (insert for example) whenever I use the create() method in the teacher object.

What is the right way to go?

**- Do I need to create a new mysqli object in each method?**

By the way - a small review to my code would be epic. Like, I would love to know if I got this right.

Comment: Pass in `$conn` to the create method?

Comment: [Core Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better fit for this kind of questions.

Comment: You mean add $sql to "create($id, $name, $phone, $vehicle)"? because this doesn't work (Warning: Missing argument 5 for Teacher::create())

Comment: By the way thanks for downvoting who ever did that. I'm sure he was a very intelligent baby that knew OOP.

Comment: for the insert use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: @Jefffrey - Interesting. Would you mind expanding on that?

Comment: About OOP: 
1) You may consider using constructors (__construct) instead of create() method
2) Do not prefix variables with _, make them private and use setters and getters instead.

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like so:

```
    private $connections = array();

    public function newConnection( $host, $user, $password, $database )
        {
            $this->connections[] = new mysqli( $host, $user, $password, $database );
            $connection_id = count( $this->connections )-1;
            if( mysqli_connect_errno() )
            {
                trigger_error('Error connecting to host. '.$this->connections[$connection_id]->error, E_USER_ERROR);
            }   


            return $connection_id;
        }

     public function closeConnection()
        {
            $this->connections[$this->activeConnection]->close();
        }

        public function insertRecords( $table, $data )
            {
                // setup some variables for fields and values
                $fields  = "";
                $values = "";

                // populate them
                foreach ($data as $f => $v)
                {

                    $fields  .= "`$f`,";
                    $values .= ( is_numeric( $v ) && ( intval( $v ) == $v ) ) ? $v."," : "'$v',";

                }

                // remove our trailing ,
                $fields = substr($fields, 0, -1);
                // remove our trailing ,
                $values = substr($values, 0, -1);

                $insert = "INSERT INTO $table ({$fields}) VALUES({$values})";
                //echo $insert;
                $this->executeQuery( $insert );
            }

public function executeQuery( $queryStr )
    {
        if( !$result = $this->connections[$this->activeConnection]->query( $queryStr ) )
        {
            trigger_error('Error executing query: ' . $queryStr .' - '.$this->connections[$this->activeConnection]->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->last = $result;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have one question - how do you connect this with the actual connection that's been set on mysql.php? what does excecuteQuery referring to?

Comment: ok should be good now

Comment: Thank you bboy. Do I need to create this method in both of my classes? (extend would solve this but I dont use the same properties in all classes)

Comment: To keep it simple you can copy and paste the ones that you need.

Comment: To learn the principles of object oriented design I recommend this book which I am currently reading and is to die for. It helped me immensely. It is in its 4 edition right now and has a collective of over 100 reviews.Most of them positiove. http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1430260319/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1/181-0078989-6887913?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_r=0FGAY6077TTGK5RN4X03&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_p=1944687702&pf_rd_i=143022925X